# Finding password in disassembled code

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, ida

I'm trying to learn reverse engineering techniques, apologies in advance if I leave anything out

I'm trying to find the password in the following section of disassembled code (there are other blocks of code in case those need to be included as well)

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
and     esp, 0FFFFFFF0h
push    esi
push    ebx
sub     esp, 158h
mov     eax, [ebp+arg_4]
mov     [esp+1Ch], eax
mov     eax, large gs:14h
mov     [esp+14Ch], eax
xor     eax, eax
mov     dword ptr [esp+2Eh], 74726170h
mov     word ptr [esp+32h], 32h
mov     dword ptr [esp+141h], 32656854h
mov     dword ptr [esp+145h], 6150646Eh
mov     word ptr [esp+149h], 7472h
mov     byte ptr [esp+14Bh], 0
mov     dword ptr [esp+4], offset aPassword ; "password:\n"
mov     dword ptr [esp], offset _ZSt4cout ; std::cout
call    __ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc ; std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,char const*)
mov     dword ptr [esp+8], 100h ; int
lea     eax, [esp+41h]
mov     [esp+4], eax    ; char *
mov     dword ptr [esp], offset _ZSt3cin ; this
call    __ZNSi3getEPci  ; std::istream::get(char *,int)
lea     eax, [esp+40h]
mov     [esp], eax
call    __ZNSaIcEC1Ev   ; std::allocator<char>::allocator(void)
lea     eax, [esp+40h]
mov     [esp+8], eax
mov     dword ptr [esp+4], offset aThisisnotthepa ; "thisisnotthepassword"
lea     eax, [esp+38h]
mov     [esp], eax
call    __ZNSsC1EPKcRKSaIcE ; std::string::string(char const*,std::allocator<char> const&)
lea     eax, [esp+40h]
mov     [esp], eax
call    __ZNSaIcED1Ev   ; std::allocator<char>::~allocator()
mov     dword ptr [esp+8], 3E8h ; n
lea     eax, [esp+41h]
mov     [esp+4], eax    ; s2
mov     dword ptr [esp], offset s1 ; "FBQ2GE9"
call    _strncmp
test    eax, eax
jnz     short loc_8048A74
```

If the compare succeeds then the password is correct

I was thinking that it would have been `FBQ2GE9`, but that's apparently the wrong answer. What am I missing here?

Comment: It's sort of interesting the `cin` goes at `esp+41h`, and the `std::allocator` instance goes at `esp+40h` (doesn't make sense, so I probably misunderstood that code)? Then `std::string(const char *, allocator)` is run over `esp+38h` (9 bytes ahead of input) ... I can't made up sense of it without debugger, as this can probably overwrite the entered string in some way (depends on the code in allocator constructor+destructor and string constructor)? Or I simply don't get it. Maybe password is "<any 9 chars>FBQ2GE9"? (surely not, as there's that "not password" string having some function too)

Comment: @Ped7g [std::allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) is stateless, as such it has no members. In C++ empty, [non sub](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo), objects are required to have size at least 1 (in this case exactly 1). So the allocator instance doesn't override the input string.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this really belongs on the reverse-engineering stack (http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strncmp at the last line, compares "input" from the string "FBQ2GE9", its like strncmp("FBQ2GE9", input, 1000) in C input came from the output string from std::istream::get(char *,int), which basically extracts a string from the address of its first param.

since this binary is ELF, cannot use a debugger cause of OS constraint, given that you know where the branch you want to change, inspect the contents of dword ptr [esp] (like from below), and offset s1, before the strncmp call is called, you'll have to trace/monitor how those data is generated by inspecting those memory addresses.

```
mov     dword ptr [esp], offset s1 ; "FBQ2GE9"
call    _strncmp
test    eax, eax
```

Something tells me that your input is manipulated so inputting FBQ2GE9 will print incorrect. Tracing this with your ELF debugger will greatly make this inspection easier

Comment: Sure, I uploaded it here: http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/588766/part1.exe   I did try thisisnotthepassword and that is not correct